# Angular ngrx-signal with RxMethod don't use initial value

Tags: angular, signals, ngrx

I would like to do some logic in the ts file of the Angular 17.2 component below that's based on a signal. I would like to use the @ngrx/signals package with rxMethod to handle my get request. However this seems to be a problem because when the code is executed, the value of the signal is the initial value.

What can i do to fix this problem? It looks to me I could convert the Signal in the component back to an observable with toObservable of rxjs-interop and than convert the response back to a Signal with toSignal, in order to have have the benefits of the Signal in the template. This feels like there is to much converting going on here...

Or perhaps I could use RxMethod in the component, but it seems nicer to have the signal related code in the store...

Not sure to handle this problem, I could use some advice

Store:

```
import { inject } from "@angular/core";
import { pipe, switchMap } from "rxjs";
import { patchState, signalStore, withMethods, withState } from "@ngrx/signals";
import { rxMethod } from "@ngrx/signals/rxjs-interop";
import { tapResponse } from "@ngrx/operators";
import { Article } from "../models/article.model";
import { ArticlesService } from "../services/articles.service";
import { ArticleListConfig } from "../models/article-list-config.model";

type ArticlesState = {
  articles: Article[];
  article: Article;
  slug: string;
  config: ArticleListConfig;
};

const initialState: ArticlesState = {
  articles: [],
  article: {
    slug: "",
    title: "",
    description: "",
    body: "",
    tagList: [],
    createdAt: "",
    updatedAt: "",
    favorited: false,
    favoritesCount: 0,
    author: {
      username: "",
      bio: "",
      image: "",
      following: false,
    },
  },
  slug: "",
  config: {
    type: "",
    filters: {
      tags: [],
    },
  },
};

export const ArticlesStore = signalStore(
  withState(initialState),
  withMethods((store, articlesService = inject(ArticlesService)) => ({
    getBySlug: rxMethod<string>(
      pipe(
        switchMap((slug) => {
          return articlesService.get(slug).pipe(
            tapResponse({
              next: (article) => patchState(store, { article }),
              error: console.error,
            })
          );
        })
      )
    ),
  }))
);
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable, inject } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Article } from "../models/article.model";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ArticlesService {
  http = inject(HttpClient);

  constructor() {}

  get(slug: string): Observable<Article> {
    return this.http
      .get<{ article: Article }>(`/articles/${slug}`)
      .pipe(map((data) => data.article));
  }

}
```

Component:

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit, effect, inject } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { ArticlesStore } from "src/app/core/stores/article.store";

@Component({
  selector: "app-editor-page",
  templateUrl: "./editor.component.html",
  imports: [ CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
  providers: [ArticlesStore],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {
  readonly articlesStore = inject(ArticlesStore);
  slug: string = "";

  constructor(
    private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    effect(() => {
      console.log(this.articlesStore.article()); // This outputs twice, first the initial value then the value based on the response
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.slug = this.route.snapshot.params["slug"];
    this.articlesStore.slug = this.route.snapshot.params["slug"];
    this.articlesStore.getBySlug(this.articlesStore.slug);
    console.log(this.articlesStore.article()); // This outputs the initial value once
  }
}
```

Comment: Your console logs are exactly what you should expect. It's working exactly as designed. You said "I would like to do some logic". Can you share what exactly you are wanting to do?

Comment: Something like this:


`if (this.articlesStore.article.author.username() === this.testUserName) {
 console.log('some more code');
} else {
 void this.router.navigate(["/"]);
}`

It always goes to the else statement, even when the usernames are the same.

Comment: Can you please include your store in the question? I don't think anyone can help without that.